# jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'group' is undefined

Tags: python, flask

I have a problem where group is undefined when calling it in html can anyone help to fix this problem?

This is the code for the webpage:

```
@app.route('/<int:group_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PUT'])
@login_required
def group(group_id):
    if not current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    group = Chatgroup.query.get(group_id)
    check = False
    for users_in_group in group.users:
        if (users_in_group.username == current_user.username):
            check = True
    if (check == False):
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    posts = group.posts
    users = group.users
    form = MessageForm()
    if form.is_submitted():
        if len(message.body.data) > 0:
            message = Message(body=message.body.data, author=current_user, group = group,
            username=current_user.username)
            db.session.add(message)
            db.session.commit()
            return render_template('groupchat.html', group=group, posts=posts, message=message)
        else:
            flash('Empty message')
            return render_template('groupchat.html', group=group, posts=posts, message=message)
```

This is the HTML code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block app_content %}
    <h1>{{_('Messages') }}</h1>
    <h2>Online gebruikers</h2>
    <body>
        <p><a href="{{url_for('groupchat')}}">Make a new groupchat</p>
        {% for online_users_element in online_users %} <!--check if users are online every-->
        <p><a href="{{ url_for('group', group_id = group.id) }}">
            {{online_users_element.username}}
        </p>
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
{% endblock %}
```

And this is the error message:

`jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'group' is undefined`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't pass a group variable on your flask route.

```
<p><a href="{{ url_for('group', group_id = group.id) }}">
```

group.id is being accessed and it is not defined on the flask route that rendered the page.

Here is my example that worked

```py
@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('home.html', group = {"id": 123})

@app.route('/<int:group_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PUT'])
def group(group_id):
    if not current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    group = Chatgroup.query.get(group_id)
    check = False
    for users_in_group in group.users:
        if (users_in_group.username == current_user.username):
            check = True
    if (check == False):
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    posts = group.posts
    users = group.users
    form = MessageForm()
    if form.is_submitted():
        if len(message.body.data) > 0:
            message = Message(body=message.body.data, author=current_user, group = group,
            username=current_user.username)
            db.session.add(message)
            db.session.commit()
            return render_template('groupchat.html', group=group, posts=posts, message=message)
        else:
            flash('Empty message')
            return render_template('groupchat.html', group=group, posts=posts, message=message)
```

Comment: If I do that I get this error message  __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'group'